# Combining inner join query result with select query result in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQl.I need to combine one join query result with another select query result. The details are,

Table one "TaskCategory" has below columns

```
cat_id
parent_id
name
type
```

I am storing both category task and subcategory tasks in same table. The category task would have parent_id as 0 and subcategory task would parent_id as the id of it's category id

I have another table TaskCategoryMeta. This table has below columns

```
cat_id,
meta_name.
meta_value
```

Only subcategories would have rows/entries in the TaskCategoryMeta table.

In the result I need the subcategories with certain meta name and meta value in TaskCategoryMeta table and all categories with parent id of 0 from TaskCategory table.

I tried below query but I got query interrupted error, please help me to achieve my result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TaskCategory
INNER JOIN TaskCategoryMeta
ON TaskCategory.cat_id = TaskCategoryMeta.cat_id where TaskCategoryMeta.cat_meta_name='HR_DEPT_SUPPORT'
and TaskCategoryMeta.cat_meta_value=1 
UNION
select * from TaskCategory where TaskCategory.cat_parent_id=0 and cat_type=1
```

Comment: I don't see why you need a union for that.  If you moved the `where` clause of the `UNION select` to the JOIN Select, you'd get the desired results.  Create a DB fiddle if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 queries, but I believe you need 2 "sections" within the where clause. To do that you need to "bind" conditions together using parentheses, and, then introduce an `OR` between the 2 sections. Note it is always helpful to indent so it is easier to understand what the parentheses contain e.g:

```
SELECT *
FROM TaskCategory
LEFT JOIN TaskCategoryMeta ON TaskCategory.cat_id = TaskCategoryMeta.cat_id
WHERE (
        TaskCategoryMeta.cat_meta_name = 'HR_DEPT_SUPPORT'
        AND TaskCategoryMeta.cat_meta_value = 1
        )
    OR (
        TaskCategory.cat_parent_id = 0
        AND cat_type = 1 -- you haven't told us which table this comes from
        )
```

As Swifty points out in a comment below, you can't use an inner join as only subcategory tasks are present in the meta table (which to me seems an odd design feature). So, instead, a left (outer) join allows for category tasks to be present in the results.

Please note `cat_type` should be prefixed by the source table name

Comment: But that way, wouldn't some of the Categories (parentid=0) be filtered out by the INNER JOIN, which is not what the OP wants?

Comment: The inner join does not have any parentid=0 condition

Comment: But wouldn't 'Only subcategories would have rows/entries in the TaskCategoryMeta table.' eliminate the Categories (not subcategories) from the INNER JOIN results?

Comment: I now see your point - I had glossed over that in the question. Yes for the 2 tables to join - and for "category tasks" to be in the resultset - an outer join is required. Curious thing that a "meta table" would not apply to all tasks, oh well.